# Prevent axis label being cutoff

Tags: output-formatting, plotting

I am running into an issue whereby my Y frame label (I want to use this rather than an axis label to make the label vertical), is being cutoff when I view the graph.

See below for an indicative example. I would like the y axis label to be "Probability of extinction", but for some reason, the displayed graph has the 'n' of extinction cutoff.

```
ListPlot[Thread[{Range[4], Table[RandomReal[], {4}]}], 
 Axes -> {True, True}, FrameLabel -> {"Probability of extinction"}, 
Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16}]
```

[image]

Can anyone advise on how to prevent this from happening? I have tried ImagePadding and ImageMargins, but neither seem to help.

Best,

Ben

Comment: Can you give a minimal example that illustrates the problem, mention your Mathematica version and your operating system?  I have never seen this problem, so I assume that it only happens under special conditions.  Let's find out what those conditions are.  Also, since you signed the question, could you set an easier to remember name in your profile than "user2003951"?

Comment: @Szabolcs - sorry about that; I meant to include my code. Please see the amendments above. Best, Ben

Comment: On my system, your code doesn't give your figure.  Nevertheless, try simply typing a space after the n, as in "Probability of extinction ".

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - Yes, that is a simple workaround! Thanks, Ben

Comment: Could you mention the version of your Mathematica and your operating system, so we can properly tag the question?  I am unable to reproduce the problem on OS X, either in M9 or M10.  Based on your and kguler's screenshots, is it M9 on Windows?

Comment: ListPlot[{1, 2, 3, 4}
 , Frame -> {True, True, False, False}
 , FrameLabel -> {{"Probability of extinction", None}, {"My X so far",
     None}}
 , LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Linux Libertine O", 18, 
   GrayLevel[0]}
 , ImageSize -> 400]

Answer (score 6):

```
dt = RandomInteger[10, 10];
```

The following reproduces the issue (Version 9.0.1.0 Windows 8 64bit) with large enough font size for the frame labels:

```
lp1 = ListPlot[dt, ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
  FrameLabel -> {None, Style["Probability of extinction", 16], None,  None}]
```

[image]

You can wrap the labels with `Framed` or `Pane` with appropriate setting for the `ImageMargins` to prevent the cropping:

```
lp2 = ListPlot[dt, ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
   FrameLabel -> {None, 
    Framed[Style["Probability of extinction", 16], FrameStyle -> None], None, None}]
```

[image]

```
lp3 = ListPlot[dt, ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
   FrameLabel -> {None, 
     Pane[Style["Probability of extinction", 16], ImageMargins -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}], None, None}]
```

[image]

**Update:** You can use the `FontTracking` option of `Style` to deal with the issue mentioned by @funnypony in the comments:

> *still another problem appears if you type "!" in the end*

```
ListPlot[dt, ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
 FrameLabel -> {None, Framed[Style["Probability of extinction!", 16], FrameStyle -> None], 
                None, None}]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[dt, ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
  FrameLabel -> {None, Framed[Style["Probability of extinction!", 16, FontTracking -> "Extended"],
         FrameStyle -> None], None, None}]
```

[image]

Comment: still another problem appears if you type "!" in the end: http://i.imgur.com/BRtrWaO.png

Comment: @funnypony, updated with a way to deal with the "!" issue.

Answer (score 3):

It seems there's a problem when mathematica renders the output image in some cases:

[image]

Thats label for 18-22 font sizes, evidently it doesn't smoothly work for 19, 20, 21. But since you increase the quality - everthing becomes perfect:

```
Rasterize[ListPlot[{{1, 2}}, FrameLabel -> {"", "Probability of extinction!"}, 
   Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> 20], ImageResolution -> 500]
```

[image]

The simplest solution though is just  to use occasionally spaces at the end, as mentioned in comments, or different font sizes.